# Rotating around a custom transformOriginPoint behaves like rotating around the standard transformOriginPoint

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene

I'm programming a physics simulation with circular objects. I move my objects around by rotating them and then advancing them into the direction they face, that makes physical equations pretty easy to process. But now I've got the problem that my circles, which I defined through a QRectF object, rotate around their origin, which isn't their center, which looks pretty silly.

I've tried using

```
 setTransformOriginPoint (mapToItem(this,40,40));
 setRotation(phi);
 setTransformOriginPoint (mapToItem(this,0,0));
```

where 40/40 is the middle of my circles but it still rotates it around the origin.

I've also tried

```
this->setTransform(QTransform()
  .translate(this->boundingRect().center().x(),this->boundingRect().center().y())
  .rotate(alpha)
  .translate(-this->boundingRect().center().x(),-this->boundingRect().center().y()));
```

but this posed the problem that it didn't change the value I got when calling rotation() on the object. I worked around that by just saving the my current rotation in my object, but this string only seems to work the first time I call it in the constructor, afterwards it glitches out completely, for example a rotation of 0 results in a displacement of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to have circles with a bounding rect centered on 0,0. Then you won't have to worry about any of that. It also makes the simulation easier, since then you are manipulating the objects at their center of mass. For example, if you want to simulate rotation (spin) of the objects when they impact with a non-zero tangential velocity (perpendicular to the contact normal), such setup will make the equations easier to follow.